# Rename several data.frame at once in R

Tags: r

At the beginning of a script I am loading all available data.frames as follows ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11433532/2950721)):

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.Rds")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], readRDS(temp[i]))
```

However, loaded data frames inherit the extension (i.e, `.Rds`). I would like to strip the `.Rds` from the `data.frame` names (for efficiency's sake, before they are created).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43368191/2950721), I found that I could use the following code: `stripExtension <- gsub('.Rds', "", temp)`. However, inserted between the 2 lines of code above, the data frames are not loaded because the extension is missing:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.Rds")
stripExtension <- gsub('.Rds', "", temp)
for (i in 1:length(stripExtension)) assign(stripExtension[i], readRDS(stripExtension[i]))
```

My question:

- How can I load multiple `.Rds` files at once and give them another name than the file name it originated from (i.e., the `.Rds` filename, but without the `.Rds` extension)?

Any help highly appreciated.

---

System used:

- R version: 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
- RStudio version: 1.4.1717
- OS: macOS Catalina version 10.15.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally worked:

```
rdsFilesFolder <- path("rdsFiles")
listOfRdsFiles <- list.files(path = rdsFilesFolder, pattern="*.Rds")
stripExtensions <- gsub('.Rds', "", listOfRdsFiles)

for (numberOfRdsFiles in 1:length(stripExtensions)) {
  assign(stripExtensions[numberOfRdsFiles], 
         readRDS(paste0("./", rdsFilesFolder, "/", listOfRdsFiles[numberOfRdsFiles])))}
```

The `for` loop has an `assign` argument that can be different from the `readRDS` argument.

This code has the added advantage to recognise filenames that start with `%` (e.g., `%5EGSPC.Rds`).

Comment: There is a function that does stripping extensions from paths: `tools::file_path_sans_ext`.

Answer (score 1):

```r
temp = list.files(pattern="[.]Rds$")
obj_nms = tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(temp))
for (i in seq_along(temp))
    assign(obj_nms[[i]], readRDS(temp[[i]]))
```

`tools` comes with r built in so you do not have to install it.
`basename` removes the directory name from the file path.